# Apache Solr: Correct use of CompoundWordFilter

Tags: solr

I'm trying to figure out how to best configure Solr for my app. I'm indexing (mostly german) PDF-Documents, and I'm using dismax queries to query Solr.

If a document contains the word "Firmenprofil" (a german compound word, -> 'company profile'), it will only be returned in queries for exactly that word. However, it would be desirable for queries only containing "Profil" to also return this document.

I downloaded a german dictionary file and applied a `DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter` to both the index- and the query-analyzer.

The Problem is, that the filter decomposes the query into **very** small parts (e.g. "pro" in the case of "Firmenprofil" which then results in having all sorts of documents that contain words like "Product" returned...).

I tried removing the Filter from the query-analyzer which leads to solr not finding the document at all. I also tried leaving the query-filter in, but explicitly setting the `onlyLongestMatch`-option to true, but that didn't seem to have any effect at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your actual config files, its a bit of a guessing game.

Did you check if profil is part of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems like my dictionary file was simply too big (~20mb). I replaced it with a more compact one and now it works just fine...

Comment: yeah, I've checked that, sry for not posting any config, but I've solved the problem now